# Batch script to create large text file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm trying to create a text file that is around 4 gig.  I have done this using a batch script but the creation took around 7 hours and so I think there must be a better way to do it.  Here's the code I am using right now:

```
echo "TOA5","CR6Series","CR6","790","CR6.Std.02.11","CPU:datatypes.CR6","26536","OneSec" > complete2.txt
echo "TIMESTAMP","RECORD","UnicodeSmpl","FP2Smpl","IEEE4Smpl","UINT2Smpl","LongSmpl","StringSmpl","BooleanSmpl","Bool8Smpl_1(1)","Bool8Smpl_1(2)","Bool8Smpl_1(3)","Bool8Smpl_1(4)","Bool8Smpl_1(5)","Bool8Smpl_1(6)","Bool8Smpl_1(7)","Bool8Smpl_1(8)","Bool8Smpl_2(1)","Bool8Smpl_2(2)","Bool8Smpl_2(3)","Bool8Smpl_2(4)","Bool8Smpl_2(5)","Bool8Smpl_2(6)","Bool8Smpl_2(7)","Bool8Smpl_2(8)","NsecSmpl" >> complete2.txt
echo "TS","RN","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","" >> complete2.txt
echo "","","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp" >> complete2.txt
for /L %%i in (0,1,23616999) do echo "2015-05-13 12:11:53",%%i,"大 不束 ロガー 233",-6388,-2.395906E+034,52338,-1715056512,"Test string",0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,"2015-05-13 12:11:53.078" >> complete2.txt
```

The first 4 lines are needed as a header to the file.  Then the for loop is used to increment a "record" number in the file and also fill the file with enough data to make it 4 gigs.  The other requirement for this file is to have each "record" on a new line.

Like I said, the current code does what I need it to do, I'm just looking for a way to speed it up significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than open, append, close, open, append, close, open, append, close, etc. for 23616999 iterations, it'll greatly improve the efficiency if you open the file one time, perform the entire loop sequence with the file open, then close it after finished.  Change your syntax thusly:

```js
rem;
@cls
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "tokens=4" %%I in ('chcp') do set "chcp=%%I"
chcp 65001 >NUL

>complete2.txt (
    echo "TOA5","CR6Series","CR6","790","CR6.Std.02.11","CPU:datatypes.CR6","26536","OneSec"
    echo "TIMESTAMP","RECORD","UnicodeSmpl","FP2Smpl","IEEE4Smpl","UINT2Smpl","LongSmpl","StringSmpl","BooleanSmpl","Bool8Smpl_1(1)","Bool8Smpl_1(2)","Bool8Smpl_1(3)","Bool8Smpl_1(4)","Bool8Smpl_1(5)","Bool8Smpl_1(6)","Bool8Smpl_1(7)","Bool8Smpl_1(8)","Bool8Smpl_2(1)","Bool8Smpl_2(2)","Bool8Smpl_2(3)","Bool8Smpl_2(4)","Bool8Smpl_2(5)","Bool8Smpl_2(6)","Bool8Smpl_2(7)","Bool8Smpl_2(8)","NsecSmpl"
    echo "TS","RN","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
    echo "","","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp"
    for /L %%i in (0,1,23616999) do echo "2015-05-13 12:11:53",%%i,"大 不束 ロガー 233",-6388,-2.395906E+034,52338,-1715056512,"Test string",0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,"2015-05-13 12:11:53.078"
)

chcp %chcp% >NUL
```

Comment: That worked awesome.  I can understand the modification to not open append close but can you help me understand what is going on here:
    for /f "tokens=4" %%I in ('chcp') do set "chcp=%%I"
chcp 65001 >NUL

Comment: The `for /f` loop captures your current codepage to a variable.  The next line changes your console codepage to Unicode.  That's to preserve the Unicode characters -- the `大 不束 ロガー 233` string.  The last line of the script changes your console codepage back the way it was.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using VBScript that has the FileSystemObject object?

Comment: I have not.  I'm not experienced at all with vbscript.  Part of the reason for using a batch file is because I have used it for smaller files just fine but I just don't know how to make it work better for large files.

Answer (score 0):

Use exponential power

```
echo "TOA5","CR6Series","CR6","790","CR6.Std.02.11","CPU:datatypes.CR6","26536","OneSec" > complete1.txt
echo "TIMESTAMP","RECORD","UnicodeSmpl","FP2Smpl","IEEE4Smpl","UINT2Smpl","LongSmpl","StringSmpl","BooleanSmpl","Bool8Smpl_1(1)","Bool8Smpl_1(2)","Bool8Smpl_1(3)","Bool8Smpl_1(4)","Bool8Smpl_1(5)","Bool8Smpl_1(6)","Bool8Smpl_1(7)","Bool8Smpl_1(8)","Bool8Smpl_2(1)","Bool8Smpl_2(2)","Bool8Smpl_2(3)","Bool8Smpl_2(4)","Bool8Smpl_2(5)","Bool8Smpl_2(6)","Bool8Smpl_2(7)","Bool8Smpl_2(8)","NsecSmpl" >> complete1.txt
echo "TS","RN","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","" >> complete1.txt
echo "","","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp","Smp" >> complete1.txt
echo "2015-05-13 12:11:53",%%i,"大 不束 ロガー 233",-6388,-2.395906E+034,52338,-1715056512,"Test string",0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,"2015-05-13 12:11:53.078" > complete2.txt
for /L %%i in (0,1,25) do type complete2.txt >> complete2.txt
type complete2.txt >> complete1.txt
```

this puts the header in complete1.txt, then puts one record into complete2.txt, then doubles the size of complete2.txt file 25 times, then finally appends complete2.txt to complete1.txt.

Generates a 4 gig file in minutes.

Comment: This was actually the first thing I tried.  It is a great trick but I need each line in the for loop to have a unique number.  This is why I use the %%i variable in line.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit in your statement.